# Limit number of blobs processed at one time by Azure Webjobs

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, azure-webjobs

I have an Azure Webjob that copies large CSVs (500 MB to 10+ GB) into a SQL Azure table. I get a new CSV every day and I only retain records for 1 month, because it's expensive to keep them in SQL, so they are pretty volatile.

To get them started, I bulk uploaded last month's data (~200 GBs) and I'm seeing all 30 CSV files getting processed at the same time.  This causes a pretty crazy backup in the uploads, as shown by this picture:

[image: Webjob results]

I have about 5 pages that look like this counting all of the retries.
If I upload them 2 at a time, everything works great!  But as you can see from the running times, some can take over 14 hours to complete.

What I want to do is bulk upload 30 CSVs and have the Webjob only process 3 of the files at a time, then once one completes, start the next one.  Is this possible with the current SDK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, absolutely possible.

Assuming the pattern you are using here is to use Scheduled or On-Demand WebJobs that pop a message on a queue which is then picked up by a constantly running WebJob that processes messages from the queue and then does the work you can use the JobHost.Queues.BatchSize property to limit the number of queue messages that can be processed at one time. H

```
static void Main()
{
    JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();

    //AzCopy cannot be invoked multiple times in the same host
    //process, so read and process one message at a time
    config.Queues.BatchSize = 1;
    var host = new JobHost(config);
    host.RunAndBlock();
}
```

If you would like to see what this looks like in action feel free to clone this GitHub repo I published recently on how to use WebJobs and AzCopy to create your own Blob Backup service. I had the same problem you're facing which is I could not run too many jobs at once.

https://github.com/markjbrown/AzCopyBackup

Hope that is helpful.

Edit, I almost forgot. While you can change the BatchSize property above you can also take advantage of having multiple VM's host and process these jobs too which basically allows you to scale this into multiple, independent, parallel processes. You may find that you can scale up the number of VM's and process the data very quickly instead of having to throttle it using BatchSize.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Processing all 30 at the same time isn't a processor or memory concern, it is the throughput to the Database that I'm worried about.  I'll try queuing up the results like you were saying and see where that gets me, though then I have to switch from triggering on blob to triggering on queue.

Comment: You can actually write two constantly running jobs in a chain. (I know this sounds absurd). One monitoring the blog which then writes to a queue, and then another monitoring the queue that does the inserts into the DB, where you can then throttle on the BatchSize.

Comment: Possibly. It kind of breaks the pattern suggested by the design of the WebJobs service however. If it's still executing too fast you can try just putting a sleep() inside the function in RunandBlock() too, see if that works.

Comment: I ended up using the Queue job that then reads the blob.  I wish the blob had a batch size property as well... Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Does config.Queues.BatchSize  work across instances i.e. if I want a singleton listener, but I happen to have deployed multiple instances? edit: I see it doesn't :(

Comment: No that doesn't work. If you have a site on multiple instances then deploy the WebJob project into its own empty site and keep that on a single instance.